# Why is my RFID card not being recognized by my reader?

Tags: arduino, rfid, raspberry-pi-pico, mfrc522

I have an `RFID-RC522` module that I recently purchased from a hobby store, it came with a `key fob` and a `card`. I was experimenting with it last night and was working just fine using Raspberry Pi Pico, but all over sudden, the card is not getting detected by the module. I thought I had a problem with my code, but then even after switching to `Arduino Uno` the card is not being read or detected, but the `key fob` is working fine. I am using the examples from the famous `MFRC522 Library` by `GitHub Community` available in the Arduino Library manager to do the tests. Could my card be destroyed or what? Is there a way to fix it?
I have seen some people with the problems with the code and connections but mine the `key fob` is working so I think it's the *card* issue.

Comment: Which Chip do you have? For DESFire there is a security lock which shuts the chip down on suspicious behavior but should come back after 30min.

Comment: It is the one that comes with the RC522 module, together with a key fob. I don't really know it's specifications. Is there a way to check these details?